# Angular: http GET method is not working just after calling http POST, but its working when i enclose the GET method with setTimeout() method. Why?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, http

I am new to Angular. Here, I was trying to add an object to a db and to display it in template simultaneously.

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'HttpRequest';
  allProducts: Product[] = [];

  @ViewChild('productsForm')
  form!: NgForm;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.fetchProducts();
  }

  onProductsFetch() {
    this.fetchProducts();
  }

  onProductCreate(products: { pName: string; desc: string; price: string }) {
    console.log(products);
    let header = new HttpHeaders({ myHeader: 'sachin' });
    this.http
      .post<{ name: string }>(
        '*****',
        JSON.stringify(products),
        { headers: header }
      )
      .subscribe({
        next: (res) => {
          // console.log(res);
        },
      });

    //--------------------Error is here-----------------------------------------

    //! This is not working
    this.onProductsFetch();

    //! This is working
    // setTimeout(() => {
    //   this.onProductsFetch();
    // }, 1000);
    //--------------------Error is here-----------------------------------------
  }

  private fetchProducts() {
    this.http
      .get<{ [key: string]: Product }>(
        '*****'
      )
      .pipe(
        map((res) => {
          let products: Product[] = [];
          for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(res)) {
            products.push({ ...value, id: key });
          }
          return products;
        })
      )
      .subscribe({
        next: (products) => {
          this.allProducts = [...products];
          console.log(this.allProducts);
        },
      });
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="main-area">
  <div class="content-area">
    <div class="header">
      <h1>Manage Products</h1>
      <hr />
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <!--Add product form-->
      <div class="form-area">
        <h3>Create Product</h3>
        <form
          #productsForm="ngForm"
          (ngSubmit)="onProductCreate(productsForm.value)"
        >
          <label>Procuct Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="pName" ngModel />

          <label>Procuct Description</label>
          <input type="text" name="desc" ngModel />

          <label>Procuct Price</label>
          <input type="text" name="price" ngModel />

          <input type="submit" value="Add Product" />
        </form>
      </div>

      <!--Display product area-->
      <div class="product-display-area">
        <h3>All Products</h3>
        <table id="products">
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
          <tr *ngFor="let prod of allProducts; let i = index">
            <td>{{ i + 1 }}</td>
            <td>{{ prod.pName }}</td>
            <td>{{ prod.desc }}</td>
            <td>${{ prod.price }}</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <hr />
        <div class="action-btn-container">
          <button class="btn-fetch" (click)="onProductsFetch()">
            Refresh Products
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**products.model.ts**

```
export class Product {
    pName!: string;
    desc!: string;
    price!: string;
    id?: string;
}
```

So here, when i use onProductCreate() method, the POST method is working but onProductFetch() isnt working and the template is not updating while if we use setTimeout(), its working completely and also template got updated. Why its happening like that?

*PS*: Please forgive me if my question is wrong :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`http.post` just returns observable immidiately and does not wait your POST get response.

You have to put your `this.onProductsFetch();` in `subscribe`.

```
    this.http
      .post<{ name: string }>(
        '******',
        JSON.stringify(products),
        { headers: header }
      )
      .subscribe({
        next: (res) => {
          // console.log(res);
          this.onProductsFetch();
        },
      });
```